# How to fix the relation between the Employee entity and Task entity to appear in the postman?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have a relation between Employee entity and Task entity but it does not appear when I insert the data in the repository, or when I Get it in Postman I think the problem is with the relation.

The relation between them is: one employee have at least one task.

This is **Employee Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Employee {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @NotEmpty(message = "Please enter the employee name!")
    private String employeeName;

    private Integer employeeNumber;

    @Embedded
    private Address address;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "task_employee",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "task_id")
    )
    private List<Task> tasks;

    public Employee(String employeeName, Integer employeeNumber, Address address) {
        this.employeeName = employeeName;
        this.employeeNumber = employeeNumber;
        this.address = address;

    }

    public Employee() {
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmployeeName() {
        return employeeName;
    }

    public void setEmployeeName(String employeeName) {
        this.employeeName = employeeName;
    }

    public Integer getEmployeeNumber() {
        return employeeNumber;
    }

    public void setEmployeeNumber(Integer employeeNumber) {
        this.employeeNumber = employeeNumber;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public List<Task> getTasks() {
        return tasks;
    }

    public void setTasks(List<Task> tasks) {
        this.tasks = tasks;
    }
}
```

**Task Entity:**

```
@Entity
public class Task {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer taskId;

    @NotEmpty(message = " Please Enter the Task name!")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tasks")
    private List<Employee> employees;

    public Task() {
    }
    public Task(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        employees = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    public Integer getTaskId() {
        return taskId;
    }
    public void setTaskId(Integer taskId) {
        this.taskId = taskId;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public List<Employee> getEmployees() {
        return employees;
    }
    public void setEmployees(List<Employee> employees) {
        this.employees = employees;
    }
}
```

This is what appear when I send GET Employee in Postman:

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "employeeName": "fahad",
    "employeeNumber": 23,
    "address": {
        "street": "salah",
        "city": "Jeddah",
        "state": "makkah",
        "postalCode": "m1"
    },
    "tasks": []
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see your Controller code but keep in mind @ManyToMany has a default fetch type of Lazy. Assuming you actually have data in the task table that also gets inserted to the task_employee join table you would either need to trigger the fetch by explicitly invoking the employee.getTasks() method or change your Fetch Type to FetchType.EAGER.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to fetch `Employee` with all associated `Task` entity. You should create a Custom query something like this in `Employee Repository`.

```
  @Query("""
    SELECT employe FROM EmployeeEntity  employe
    JOIN FETCH employe.tasks """)
  List<Employee> getAllEmployersWithWithTasks();
```

And also in `Task Entity` add one more annotation on `private List<EmployeeEntity> employees;` field.

Something like this:

```
  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tasks")
  @JsonIgnore
  private List<Employee> employees;
```

`@JsonIgnore` is used to eliminate `circular reference` in `JSON Serialization` or you can use [DTO projection](https://vladmihalcea.com/spring-jpa-dto-projection/) if you dont want to use `@JsonIgnore`.

And that is all. The wanted result will look something like this(in Postman):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The default fetch type for many to many relation will be like `fetch = FetchType.LAZY`

You may try this query

```
@Query(value = "SELECT t FROM Task t "
    + "JOIN FETCH t.employees te "
    + "WHERE te.id = :employeeId")
List<Task> findTasksByEmployeeId(@Param("employeeId") Integer employeeId);
```

to query the related tasks for this specific employee using employee's id

and set it back to the `List<Task> tasks` in the employee object when returning it